# Extract lines from a list that has a double-repeated character

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

i have a text file
 I need to Extract lines from a list that has a double-repeated character

For example, I have

> cat-dog-eat
>
> men-boy

I need to Extract lines double-repeated -

and the desired output is:

> cat-dog-eat

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is helpful for you to do your own research before posting to SO; SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Line with **at least 2** or **exactly 2** hyphens?

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

```
kent$  cat file
cat-dog-eat
men-boy
a-b-c-d-e
```

To get lines have exactly two `-`s:

```
awk -F'-' 'NF==3' file
cat-dog-eat
```

To get lines have at least two `-`s:

```
awk -F'-' 'NF>2' file
cat-dog-eat
a-b-c-d-e
```